# asyncio.StreamWriter is paused, what should i do?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am writing an application, using asyncio sockets

And after sending requests in cycle

```
while request_screen:
     writer.write(b'screenshare')
     await writer.drain()`
```

i noticed that before cycle writer looks like that:

```
<StreamWriter transport=<_ProactorSocketTransport fd=1168 read=<_OverlappedFuture pending overlapped=<pending, 0x1bc7ca13a30> cb=[_ProactorReadPipeTransport._loop_reading()]> write=<_OverlappedFuture finished result=3>> reader=<StreamReader waiter=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]> transport=<_ProactorSocketTransport fd=1168 read=<_OverlappedFuture pending overlapped=<pending, 0x1bc7ca13a30> cb=[_ProactorReadPipeTransport._loop_reading()]> write=<_OverlappedFuture finished result=3>>>>
```

And after:

```
<StreamWriter transport=<_ProactorSocketTransport fd=1168 write=<_OverlappedFuture finished result=3>> reader=<StreamReader 173203 bytes transport=<_ProactorSocketTransport fd=1168 write=<_OverlappedFuture finished result=3>> paused>>
```

How to fix it?

I didnt tried anything because i don't know the reason of this problem

I expected to continue using sockets for sending requests, but now
sockets are paused and dont send any requests

Comment: "it looks like that" -- WHAT looks like that?  Are you quite sure the other side is still listening?

Comment: yes, i restarted server and client successfully reconnected

Comment: sorry, i meant writer